# Matrices over the Cuntz algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the Cuntz algebra $O_2$. Is it true that $M_2(O_2)$ is isomorphic to $O_2$? I was trying to show that is impossible but now I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. In fact, if $A$ is a simple, separable, unital, nuclear $C^{\ast}$-algebra, then $A\otimes O_2 \cong O_2$. This is a theorem of Kirchberg [See Theorem 7.1.2 in [Rordam's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540423058)]

Comment: Is the conclusion also true in the non-unital case?